# Serving ASP.NET in Windows 7 IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, iis-7, permissions

I have worked with IIS 5.1 (XP) and 6 (Server 2003) but I am a little lost on IIS 7 (Windows 7).

I install IIS from windows component, created a new website `testweb`, added virtual directory, pointed it to where to serve pages from. Converted that to application. Now when I visis the site, it does go to the location and it lists all the files (I have enabled directory listing) but when I when I go to the test.htm file (I added) in the folder, I get this

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

The file is obviously there as it was listed in the directory. If I click on .aspx file I get this

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler "ASPX handler" has a
>   bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

One problem that I had was I could not save test.htm file directly in the directory (c:\program files\product\web) from Visual Studio, I had to save the file in documents folder and then copy it over as administrator.

---

My questions are:

1. Do I need to specify default handlers in II7 for ASPX pages? I heard they are not there by default. This would be in Hanlders section. I have already added one by the way.
2. Do I have to add MIME type for ASPX pages as well. They are not there be default. If I had one, I run into different errors.

Can anyone clarify on the two questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For #1, [did you install the static file portion of IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx)?

For #2, try re-registering ASP.Net 4.0 by running something like:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

(Depending your CPU you might want to use Framework64)

Also check that your app pool is targeting the 4.0 Framework and not the 2.0 Framework.

Comment: that's helpful. I have 64 bit Win7 btw and am running .NET 2.0 application, not .net 4.

Comment: this has put me in the right direction. static pages were enabled though. In another section, I enabled ASP and ASP.NET and now I am getting .net error (website related). I do not see directory listing anymore though. For test.htm, I am still getting the same error (it is not served). The directory listing has gone.

Comment: Try removing the `web.config` file from the equation, just rename it to `web.config.old` or something and see if you get a different error message.